# How to use devise helpers in a rake task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise, scheduled-tasks, rake-task

My task will do the following:

- Check if a user is signed in, and notify it to an admin

  - If true => do nothing
  - If false => send an email to an admin

I want this task to be executed every hour (it will be scheduled with Heroku Scheduler add-on)

The problem here is that you cannot use `user_signed_in?` or `current_user` in any rake file you write. In addition, I can not pass any of these values as parameters because It will be called from the Heroku Scheduler, dashboard.

Some of my code here:

**lib/tasks/scheduler.rake**

```
task :send_notification => :environment do
  if user_signed_in?
    puts "No need to email"
  else
    puts "Sending email"
    u=User.find(132)   #get an admin user
    ModelMailer.time_notification(u).deliver
  end
end
```

The error:

```
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `user_signed_in?' for main:Object
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Devise in its default configuration does not allow you to track which users are online and offline. The helpers `current_user` and `user_signed_in?` pertain to the current session and are only valid during a user's request. Since there is no request in a rake task, they aren't useful.

You could potentially add a column to your database to track whether users are signed in or signed out, but this functionality isn't present in devise.